# Como puedo imprimir el indice de un array usando el for of

Tags: javascript

El resultado que busco es imprimir por consola los indices del array minerales pero no tengo claro como hacerlo.

el resultado que busco es  0 1 2 3.

```js
 let minerales = ["oro","plata","platino","bronce"];

for(let [key, value] of minerales) {
 console.log(`Mineral=${value} numero${key}  `)

}
```

Comment: Tiene que ser con `for of`? Puedes hacerlo con `forEach` y es mucho más sencillo.

Comment: Quiero saber si se puede hacer con el for of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te dejo el ejemplo con `forEach.()` y con el `for of` necesitas del método `entries()` para hacer lo que requieres.

```js
let minerales = ["oro","plata","platino","bronce"];

minerales.forEach(function(mineral, indice){

  console.log(`Usando forEach, Este es el indice: ${indice}`);

});


for (const [i, v] of minerales.entries()) {
  console.log(`Usando for of, este es el indice: ${i}`)
}
```